# How to convert a RegionPlot3D to a 2D temperature plot?

Tags: plotting, legending

How to convert this `RegionPlot3D` to a `DensityPlot` having `z` as the colour axis, here is one code sample

```
  RegionPlot3D[{10^y < 10^23*10^(z - x), 10^y > 10^25 10^-x , 10^y > 10^26*10^-x , 10^y < 
  10^57*10^(-2 x + 4 z/3), 10^y > 10^-164*10^(-8 z + 5 x)}, {x, 28, 31}, {y, -8, 
  1}, {z, -3, -1}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> None, 
  Axes -> {True, True, True}, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic]]
```

For simplicity, if you try to plot a 2D region of `x` vs `z` varying `y` from `-8` to `1` you will see a parametric shifting of a triangular region. I need to superimpose all those regions with varying colours to a single plot and add the colour axis `y` to show the parametric change. An example of this can be seen if one can superimpose the different coloured circles to the same plot showing the change by a colour axis `a`.
Example:

```
 Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[(x - a)^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[a]]], {a, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Five HalfSpaces : `ineqs = {10^y < 10^23*10^(z - x), 10^y > 10^25 10^-x,     10^y > 10^26*10^-x, 10^y < 10^57*10^(-2 x + 4 z/3),     10^y > 10^-164*10^(-8 z + 5 x)}; ineqs = ineqs /. Power[10, expr_] :> expr`

Comment: @cvgmt I understood your point my equations are unnecessarily complicated by `10^`, but is it possible to get the allowed region by the halfspaces as a 2D `DensityPlot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can retrieve data directly from `RegionPlot3D`. In this case there are 5   regions combined in one plot. Therefore we need 5 plots to convert 3D in 2D. First step

```
R=RegionPlot3D[{10^y < 10^23*10^(z - x), 10^y > 10^25 10^-x, 
  10^y > 10^26*10^-x, 10^y < 10^57*10^(-2 x + 4 z/3), 
  10^y > 10^-164*10^(-8 z + 5 x)}, {x, 28, 31}, {y, -8, 
  1}, {z, -3, -1}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> None, 
 Axes -> {True, True, True}, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic]]
```

Second step

```
data[i_] := R[[1, 1, 1, i]][[1]];
```

Visualization

```
{R, Table[
  ListDensityPlot[data[i], PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   PlotRange -> All], {i, 5}]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Update 1. To visualize regions in one plot we can use

```
n = Length[Range[-3, -1, 1/20]]; frame = 
 Table[RegionPlot[{10^y < 10^23*10^(z - x), 10^y > 10^25 10^-x, 
    10^y > 10^26*10^-x, 10^y < 10^57*10^(-2 x + 4 z/3), 
    10^y > 10^-164*10^(-8 z + 5 x)}, {x, 28, 31}, {y, -8, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> RGBColor[1, 1, 1, 1/n], 
   BoundaryStyle -> {RGBColor[4/3 + (z/3), -z/3, 4/3 + z/3], 
     Thick}], {z, -3, -1, 1/n}];
Show[frame]
```

In this picture we can clearly recognize colored regions shown above
[image: Figure 2]

We also can animate solution at different `z` as follows

```
frames = 
 Table[Show[Take[frame, i]], {i, Length[frame]}]; ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Thank you, for your nice try. I really appreciate it. I have updated my question a bit to make it more easily understandable. I think it will be a perfect 2D map if one superimposes all those regions with varying colours to a single plot and add the colour axis

Comment: @darkknight Do you mean `Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[{10^y < 10^23*10^(z - x), 10^y > 10^25 10^-x, 
   10^y > 10^26*10^-x, 10^y < 10^57*10^(-2 x + 4 z/3), 
   10^y > 10^-164*10^(-8 z + 5 x)}, {x, 28, 31}, {y, -8, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[z]]], {z, -3, -1}]` ?

Comment: yes I do mean the parametric variation of the triangular allowed region with `z` but instead of `Manipulate` I want to get the triangular region in a single saveable image as a temperature map where the colour axis (`z`) will indicate the change of the area of the triangle with `z`.

Comment: @darkknight It is possible with lines only, not with solid colors. Since regions have intersections.

Comment: yes, you are correct. But I need a region like this but it will be better if the region lines become invisible, then it may look like a temperature map

Comment: `Legended[Show[
  Table[RegionPlot[{10^y > 10^23*10^(z - x) && 10^y < 10^25 10^-x && 
      10^y < 10^26*10^-x && 10^y > 10^57*10^(-2 x + 4 z/3) && 
      10^y < 10^-164*10^(-8 z + 5 x)}, {x, 28, 31}, {y, -8, 1}, 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[-z/5]], 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[1]], {z, -3, -1, 0.1}], 
  PlotRange -> {{28, 31}, {-1, -8}}, 
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 16, Bold] & /@ {"x", "y"})], 
 BarLegend[{Hue[-#/5] &, {-3, -1}}, 
    Bold}, LegendLabel -> "z"]]`

Comment: @darkknight Sorry, I don't understand you. May be you have some example? What do you try to demonstrate with the last code?

Comment: If you successfully run this code, you will see a superposition of triangles representing the allowed region on the `x-y` plane for different values of `z`. The color bar shows a correlation between the area of the triangles and increasing values of `z`. I appreciate your hard work and accept your answer.

Comment: @darkknight Thank you. If you need the color bar to my plot, then use `bar = BarLegend[{Table[
    RGBColor[4/3 + (z/3), -z/3, 4/3 + z/3], {z, -3, -1, 
     1/n}], {-3, -1}}, Range[-3, -1, 1/n]]`